# get image preview on upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i need to upload an image and then display a thumbnail preview of the image on the same page (#AJAX). can anyone provide me with some pointers?

Comment: Don't you need to submit the form (reload the page) to upload the image?  Or am I missing something with how your code works?

Comment: that sounds like the tricky part to me.  im not familiar, but i think there are ways around this.  http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 2):

index.html

```
<script>
function ajaxFileUpload(upload_field)
{
// Checking file type
var re_text = /\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg/i;
var filename = upload_field.value;
if (filename.search(re_text) == -1) {
alert("File should be either jpg or gif or jpeg");
upload_field.form.reset();
return false;
}
document.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML = '<div><img src="images/progressbar.gif" border="0" /></div>';
upload_field.form.action = 'upload-picture.php';
upload_field.form.target = 'upload_iframe';
upload_field.form.submit();
upload_field.form.action = '';
upload_field.form.target = '';
return true;
}
</script>

<!-- iframe used for ajax file upload-->
<!-- debug: change it to style="display:block" -->
<iframe name="upload_iframe" id="upload_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<!-- iframe used for ajax file upload-->

<form name="pictureForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<span>Upload Picture :</span>
<input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" onchange="return ajaxFileUpload(this);" />
<span id="picture_error"></span>
<div id="picture_preview"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

upload-picture.php

```
<?php
$upload_dir = 'upload/'; // Directory for file storing
$preview_url = 'http://localhost/image_upload/upload/';
$filename= '';
$result = 'ERROR';
$result_msg = '';
$allowed_image = array ('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/pjpeg','image/png');
define('PICTURE_SIZE_ALLOWED', 2242880); // bytes

if (isset($_FILES['picture']))  // file was send from browser
{
 if ($_FILES['picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)  // no error
 {
 if (in_array($_FILES['picture']['type'], $allowed_image)) {
 if(filesize($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']) <= PICTURE_SIZE_ALLOWED) // bytes
 {
 $filename = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$filename);

//phpclamav clamscan for scanning viruses
//passthru('clamscan -d /var/lib/clamav --no-summary '.$upload_dir.$filename, $virus_msg); //scan virus
$virus_msg = 'OK'; //assume clamav returing OK.
if ($virus_msg != 'OK') {
unlink($upload_dir.$filename);
$result_msg = $filename." : ".FILE_VIRUS_AFFECTED;
$result_msg = '<font color=red>'.$result_msg.'</font>';
$filename = '';
}else {
// main action -- move uploaded file to $upload_dir
$result = 'OK';
}
}else {
$filesize = filesize($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']);// or $_FILES['picture']['size']
$filetype = $_FILES['picture']['type'];
$result_msg = PICTURE_SIZE;
}
}else {
$result_msg = SELECT_IMAGE;
}
}
elseif ($_FILES['picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE)
$result_msg = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
else
$result_msg = 'Unknown error';
}

// This is a PHP code outputing Javascript code.
echo '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">'."\n";
echo 'var parDoc = window.parent.document;';
if ($result == 'OK') {
echo 'parDoc.getElementById("picture_error").innerHTML =  "";';
}
else {
echo "parDoc.getElementById('picture_error').innerHTML = '".$result_msg."';";
}

if($filename != '') {
echo "parDoc.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML = '<img src=\'$preview_url$filename\' id=\'preview_picture_tag\' heigh=\'100\' width=\'100\' name=\'preview_picture_tag\' />';";
}

echo "\n".'</script>';
exit(); // do not go futher

?>
```

**Make two folders**

```
 images -- keep any loading image.
 upload -- change permission.
```

**Put all these file in**

```
   image_upload
     images
     upload
     index.html
     upload-picture.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Presumably the server that you are uploading to stores the image somewhere and makes it available via some URL.  If so, then all you should need to do is have the server return the URL of the image back as part of the response to the upload request, and then have some JavaScript that adds a new `<img>` tag to the document that points at the image on the server.

To save on bandwidth, you may also want to resize the image down to an appropriate thumbnail size (using something like ImageMagick), and send back the URL of the thumbnail instead of the URL for the full-size image.